# How to split a line by equal to using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to split a line which has = using batch script. 
For e.g. 
Line is :- 
a=5
Then I want the output as :-
a
5

On searching for a solution I figured out that we can use 'for' loop to split characters like ; space tab etc 
For e.g. :- To split a line using ';' the code is as follows:-

set teststring=This;is;my;new;laptop
for /f "delims=;" %%a in ("!teststring!") do set substring=%%a
echo !substring!

Output is :-
This
is
my
new
laptop

But if my line contains '=', I cannot use a similar approach to split by '='

If anybody can help me with this it would be highly appreciated :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `delims==` to split by `=`.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("a=5") do echo %%a %%b
```

This writes out:

```
a 5
```

Comment: I just tried, and it does split on the `=`.  I've updated my answer, adding the `tokens` keyword.  Does that do what you need?

Comment: Nate thanks for your reply, its working :)
I was trying without tokens so it was failing for me.
Thanks again